# What to use for cross-browser XML handling?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, sarissa

I haven't been updated for a while on the web development so bear with me.

What are people using nowadays for XML handling in browsers? I can rember that **Sarissa** was hot some years ago. But today is **jQuery** that has taken over or something else? Or is still good old **JavaScript** and browser checking code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to parse or traverse XML, then jQuery is more than up the task. I would recommend it as a starting point.

Comment: What about when doing the whole thing? Creating xml docs, parsing, etc? Is E4X something I need to look in to?

Comment: jQuery will parse XML just fine, and is also great for consuming it via AJAX. I am not as familiar with creating XML using it...